# Is there any way by which all modules starting with same names related to any particular module name can be installed with a python script?

Tags: python

I am a newbie at some things. Can anyone pls help...

Can there be any way by which I can install all the modules related to a particular module like for example pygame has several plug-ins -
pygame-menu,
pygame-input,
pygame-input,
pygame-widgets,
pygame-geometry,
pygame-anisprite,
pygame-pgu,
dinosaur-pygame,
pygame-gui,
pygame-engine,
pygame-assets,
utils-pygame,
pygame-txt,
pygame-ai,
pygame-vkeyboard,
pygame-dashboard,
pygame-minesweeper,
pygame-spritesheet, etc

And I literally have to download all those which I need manually, one-by-one which is time consuming.
Can there be any way by which all the modules which have pygame in it be downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a requirements file and you can call it to download and install all the required Modules at oneshot.

```
pip install -r requirement.txt
```

The file looks like this

```
#requirement.txt

numpy==1.18.4
openpyxl==3.0.3
pandas==1.0.3
pefile==2019.4.18
PyInstaller==3.6
pylint==2.5.3
```